# Performance Benefits of using a Generic Handler over a Web User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

We have a simple `user control` (`.ascx`) that returns an SVG graphic when requested.

I was debating whether to convert it to a `generic handler` (`.ashx`) to squeeze a little more performance out of it. Is it going to be worth the (minor) investment of time that this will require or should I leave it as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My philosophy is that if you are outputting a content-type other than HTML then a generic handler is nearly always a better choice than an .aspx page.

Firstly, a handler makes it more obvious that this isn't just another web page. When looking at a solution, it is clear that a handler is doing something other than rendering HTML.

Secondly, the life-cycle of a generic handler is much reduced to that of an .aspx web-form page. This will have a performance benefit, as lots of events are skipped and things like session state aren't checked for (unless you mark it with the `IReadOnlySessionState` interface), though it probably won't be really noticeable unless your page is being requested a lot. (And if you are outputting SVG then probably that would be the main overhead).

But from an architecture point-of-view then it is the best choice.